# Plotting multiple dendrogram plots by ggplot and faceting them by 2 two methods by ggplot, R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like below.

```
sakubun<-read.csv("https://www.iwanami.co.jp/files/moreinfo/0298960/sakubun259f.csv",
                  row.names=1, 
                  fileEncoding = 'cp932')
sakubunp<-sakubun/rowSums(sakubun)
```

I applied cluster analysis to this data frame and try to plot the result. Cluster analysis has two different part and each has multiple methods. So the result can be a multitude of patterns, as many as the combination of these methods applied together.

I want to show multiple results as well as which combination is applied in one picture.
I succeeded in putting the results into list object.
My code is as following

```
d.method <- c("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary", "minkowski")
c.method <- c("ward.D", "ward.D2", "single", "complete", "average", "mcquitty", "median", "centroid")

result_list <- list()

for (i in 1:length(d.method)) {
  for (j in 1:length(c.method)) {
    cl_plot <- hclust(dist(sakubunp[, -32], method = d.method[i]), method = c.method[j]) %>% 
      stats::as.dendrogram() %>%
      dendextend::as.ggdend() %>% 
      ggplot2::ggplot()
    
    result_list[[paste(d.method[i], c.method[j], sep = "_")]] <- cl_plot
  }
}
```

In my data, there can be six methods for "d.method" and eight for "c.method", so there will be 6x8=48 patterns of plots and I want to arrange them into a matrix-form (column = d.method, row = c.method).

But i can't find how to put them into plots, with using `ggplot::facet_grid()` function. How can I make such a plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be ggplot's facetting facilities, you can use base R's graphic parameter `mfrow` and walk through your dataframe, casting one plot per row like this:

- create dataframe `d` with one row per method combination:

```
d.method <- c("euclidean", "maximum", "manhattan", "canberra", "binary", "minkowski")
c.method <- c("ward.D", "ward.D2", "single", "complete", "average", "mcquitty", "median", "centroid")

d <- 
  setNames(expand.grid(d.method, c.method),
           c('d.method', 'c.method')
           )
```

```
> d |> head(2)
   d.method c.method
1 euclidean   ward.D
2   maximum   ward.D
```

- prepare a multifigure panel with `mfrow` (better make the plot window really large, adjust plot parameters as needed: `?par`):

```
par(mfrow = c(8, 6),
    mar = rep(1, 4) ## decrease outer margin (= gap between facets)
    )
```

- create one `hclust` object per row (remember to wrap the result into a list) and
- plot it in one `mutate`-go:

```
library(dplyr)

d |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(clust = 
           ## you can pack anything (like a cluster result) in a *list* column:
           list( 
             iris[1:4] |>
             dist(method = d.method) |>
             hclust(method = c.method)
           ),
         plot(clust,
              main = paste(c.method, d.method, sep =', ') , sub = '', 
              labels = FALSE,
              xlab = '', ylab = '')
         )
```

[image: facetted plot with base R and dplyr]